# Fatal error</b>: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'deporte' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, api, post

Estoy haciendo un método para insertar datos en la bd pero no puedo solucionar este error, agradecería mucho su ayuda. El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
//Insertar nueva pista
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO pistas (deporte, reserva) VALUES (:deporte, :reserva)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        //se envian los valores
        $stmt->bindValue(':deporte', $_POST['deporte']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':reserva', $_POST['reserva']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $idPost = $pdo->lastInsertId(); //id de esta reserva
        if($idPost){ //si existe ese id
            header("HTTP/1.1 201 pista creada correctamente");
            echo json_encode($idPost); //devuelve el id de la reserva
            exit;
        }else{
            header("HTTP/1.1 403 error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Prueba `var_export($_POST['deporte'])`, porque tiene pinta de que no tiene ningun valor.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentacion PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce)

Tambien cabe decir que en este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71576920/uncaught-pdoexception-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1048-col) lo solucionan.

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO pistas (deporte, reserva) VALUES (:deporte, :reserva)";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            //se envian los valores
            $deporte = $_POST['deporte'] ?? '';
            $stmt->bindValue(':deporte', $deporte);
            $stmt->bindValue(':reserva', $_POST['reserva']);
            $stmt->execute();
            $idPost = $pdo->lastInsertId(); //id de esta reserva
            if($idPost){ //si existe ese id
                header("HTTP/1.1 201 pista creada correctamente");
                echo json_encode($idPost); //devuelve el id de la reserva
                exit;
            }else{
                header("HTTP/1.1 403 error");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error es claro: *`Column 'deporte' cannot be null`* significa que la columna `deporte` tiene una restricción `not null` en la definición de la tabla y estás intentando insertar un valor `null` en ella.

Para evitar esto, debes controlar el valor, para rechazar la inserción en caso de tener valores nulos, o definir un valor por defecto en esos casos, ya eso depende de la naturaleza de tu aplicación y lo que hayas definido en tu diseño.

Podrías resolverlo de este modo:

```
//Insertar nueva pista
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $deporte=$_POST['deporte'] ?? NULL;
    $reserva=$_POST['reserva'] ?? NULL;
    if ($deporte && $reserva) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO pistas (deporte, reserva) VALUES (:deporte, :reserva)";
        if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            //se envian los valores
            $stmt->bindValue(':deporte', $deporte);
            $stmt->bindValue(':reserva', $reserva);
            $stmt->execute();
            $idPost = $pdo->lastInsertId(); //id de esta reserva
            if($idPost){ //si existe ese id
                $code=201;
                $msg="pista creada correctamente. Id: $idPost";
            } else {
                $code=403;
                $msg="No se creó el ID";
            }
        } else {
            $code=403;
            $msg="Error preparando la consulta";
        }
    } else {
        $code=403;
        $msg="Alguno de los valores a insertar está vacío o es nulo";
    }
} else {
    $code=403;
    $msg="Método no permitido";
}
header("HTTP/1.1 $code $msg");
exit;
```